# Get 1st day and last day from number month

Tags: excel, vba

Let's suppose in **A1** I have **1** (for me is month number) that is January.

How can I get the **1st** day and the **last day** for the current year, given the **month number 4**? (IN VBA IF POSSIBLE)

Didn't try code because I found only formulas on the internet but nothing with month number...

Every links and suggestions are accepted aswell

Comment: Is using VBA a must? You can do this quite simply using formulas, and do you always want to take the year using today's date?

Answer (score 3):

One option is with [`DateSerial`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateserial-function) and [`DateAdd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateadd-function):

```
Sub Test()
    Dim monthNum As Long
    monthNum = 4

    Dim firstDay As Date
    firstDay = DateSerial(Year(Date), monthNum, 1)

    Dim lastDay As Date
    lastDay = DateAdd("m", 1, firstDay) - 1    
End Sub
```

**EDIT**: You can also use `DateSerial` for the last day:

```
DateSerial(Year(Date), monthNumber + 1, 0)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the links! Definetly worth asking here!

Comment: Interestingly enough, the following will also give you the last day of the month: `DateSerial(Year(Date), monthNumber + 1, 0)`

Comment: @Guest yes that is much better than `DateAdd`, thanks for pointing out!

Comment: You can also use `WorksheetFunction.EOMONTH(firstday,0)`

Comment: @DarrellH yes that is an option too.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like the below. It is definitely a workaround as I am sure someone else will have a better solution!

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub GetLastDay()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim lMonth As Long, dDateTest As Date

    'april
    lMonth = 4

    'first date
    Debug.Print "First day in month is always 1"

    'last day
    '31 is max in any given month
    For i = 1 To 32
        dDateTest = DateSerial(Year(Date), lMonth, i)
        If Month(dDateTest) <> lMonth Then
            Debug.Print "Last day in month = " & (i - 1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Resulting print out:

`Last day in month = 30`

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for you. lets assume you have the number of the months in Column A and the first date & last date of the same month number should reflect in Column B and C respectively:

```
Dim mnt As Long, xrow As Long
Dim i As Long, Ws As Worksheet
Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
xrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To xrow
    Ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = "=date(year(today()),RC[-1],1)"
    Ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = "=eomonth(RC[-1],0)"
Next i

End Sub
```

Hope That Helps